# The server tag is not well formed in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have the hyperlink control on the GridView and I want to call the javascript function with passing parameters. I am getting Server Tag is not well formed error. I tried changing double quotes to single quote etc, still the same issue.
Can anyone help me find the issue here .

```
Line 1946:                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transaction Id">
Line 1947:                        <ItemTemplate>
Line 1948:                        <asp:HyperLink ID="lbltransId"
                                     runat="server" 
                           Text="<%# "<a href=\"javascript:subViewBookingDetails('"+ 
                           Eval("transId") + 
                           "','','','','',,'','','')\">" + 
                          Eval("transId") + "</a>" %>"></asp:HyperLink>
Line 1949:                        </ItemTemplate>
Line 1950:                        <FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: Don't use the `<%#` syntax within a server control, set the property in code behind

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Do not use Text to populate link inside, use NavigateUrl instead.

```
      <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" 
        NavigateUrl="<%# String.Format(
       "javascript:subViewBookingDetails({0} ,,,,,,,,)", Eval("transId"))%>"
        Text="<%#Eval("transId") %>"
        runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Can you please copy/paste html code produced on loading of this page?

Comment: Line 1946:                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transaction Id">
Line 1947:                        <ItemTemplate>
Line 1948:                            <asp:HyperLink id="lbltransId" NavigateUrl="<%# String.Format("javascript:subViewBookingDetails({0} ,'','','','','','','',)", Eval("transId"))%>" Text="<%#Eval("transId") %>" runat="server"/> 
Line 1949:                        </ItemTemplate>
Line 1950:                        <FooterTemplate>

Comment: This is not what I mean. I need to see HTML output from the running page (in browser)

Answer (score 0):

Text='<%# "" + Eval("transId") + "" %>'